# Laravel L5 complex validation of array data

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, laravel-5

In my application, have a form that could (theoretically) have infinite `task` and I want to define a validation rule in my `Request` that checks that none of them is equals to each others:

From:

```
<select name="task[1][id][]" class="form-control">
```

..

```
<select name="task[2][id][]" class="form-control">
```

..
..

```
<select name="task[n][id][]" class="form-control">
```

Since I am still not familiar enough with Laravel validations, I was naiv and tried things like:

```
'task[1][id][]' => 'different:task[2][id][]', 'task[2][id][]' => 'different:task[1][id][]'
```

or:

```
'task[1][id][*]' => 'different:task[2][id][*]', 'task[2][id][*]' => 'different:task[1][id][*]'
```

or:

```
'task[*][id][*]' => 'different:task[*][id][*]'
```

I do not get any error, but the validation always passes. I am pretty sure, that there is a good way to get this thing running, but I think that I am on the wrong way..

*edit: (additional information as requested)*

```
<select name="task[1][id][]" class="form-control">
      <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
      @foreach ($users as $user)
          <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->email }}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>

<select name="task[2][id][]" class="form-control">
      <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
      @foreach($users as $user)
         <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->email }}</option>
       @endforeach
</select>
```

For now, I am using "hardcoded" `<select>`. Nothing special...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `distinct`

```
$rules = [
  'task.*.id.*'=>'distinct'
]
```

Comment: `'task.*'=>'distinct'` but also `'task.id.*' => 'distinct'`is not working.

Comment: show your view code, your select form code, this should work fine for arrays

Comment: show your real view code, something like generating select field with foreach may be,, or you could `dd($request)` and show us

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but there is one last thing: how could I ignore "empty" ìd`?

Comment: add this `nullable|distinct`